# How to embed layout in shiny widgets within R Markdown?

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I want to embed shiny code within a markdown document. From what I've seen, there are two options:

1. have only the widget and output in a code chunk
2. embed a full shiny application

However, my goal is to break down one full shiny app within different parts. If I create and embed a shiny app for each part, I have no idea how to make the values flow from one app to another. If I only include widgets, I can't retain the UI design.

So my question is, is it possible to have layout around the shiny widgets within a code chunk?

For example:

```
fluidPage(
    tabPanel("Example",
             titlePanel("Example"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 checkboxInput('simple', 'Simple Widget', TRUE)
)))))
```

Instead of just:

```
checkboxInput('simple', 'Simple Widget', TRUE)
```

Inside a markdown code chunk.

Thanks!